# Google Play Store "df-dferh-01" error with react native release apk using EXPO?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I am unable to download app from GOOGLE play store. It gives "df-dferh-01" error

**How I created apk :**

-I have created apk using Expo (I asked expo to handle all signing of keystone for me )

**What doesn't work:**

-Installing from google play store
-Installing via internal testing tool

**What is working :**

-Same Release APK works if I install it directly.
-Its working fine for Apple App store

[image]